# Why is my ArrayList not filling properly?

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist

I am querying my Firebase database to retrieve street addresses, latitudes, and longitudes, and then put them in ArrayLists. However, the ArrayList is empty when I first run the activity, and only when I click back to the previous activity and then forward again, does the Array get filled. Also, when I go back to the previous activity and forward multiple times the ArrayList keeps filling up with the same info, duplicating everything.

When the activity is first opened, the Log shows:
set address(address1)
set address(address2)
set address(address3)
get address()
get address()

When the activity is refreshed,
get address(address1, address2, address3) //(this is what I want)

When the activity is refreshed again,
get address(address1, address2, address3, address1, address2, address3)

```
public void queryLocation() {

mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebases = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");
        firebaseLocationQuery = firebases.orderByChild("Locations");
        firebaseLocationQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                FirebaseLocations.firebaseLocations(dataSnapshot);
            }

            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            }

            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            }

            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
            }

            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
            }
        });
    }
```

FirebaseLocations.java

```
 public class FirebaseLocations {

        private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
        public static List<String> firebaseStreetAddress1 = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        public static List<Double> firebaseLatitude = new ArrayList<Double>(0);
        public static List<Double> firebaseLongitude = new ArrayList<Double>(0);

        public FirebaseLocations() {
        }

        public static void firebaseLocations(DataSnapshot ds) {

            firebaseStreetAddress1.add(ds.child("Locations/Address_1").getValue().toString());
            FirebaseLocations.setFirebaseStreetAddress1(firebaseStreetAddress1);

            firebaseLatitude.add((Double) ds.child("Locations/Latitude").getValue());
            FirebaseLocations.setFirebaseLatitude(firebaseLatitude);

            firebaseLongitude.add((Double) ds.child("Locations/Longitude").getValue());
            FirebaseLocations.setFirebaseLongitude(firebaseLongitude);
        }

        public static List<String> getFirebaseStreetAddress1() {
            Log.d(TAG, "get address" + firebaseStreetAddress1);
            return firebaseStreetAddress1;
        }

        public static List<Double> getFirebaseLatitude() {
            Log.d(TAG, "get lat" + firebaseLatitude);
            return firebaseLatitude;
        }

        public static List<Double> getFirebaseLongitude() {
            Log.d(TAG, "get long" + firebaseLongitude);
            return firebaseLongitude;
        }

        public static void setFirebaseStreetAddress1(List<String> firebaseStreetAddress11) {
            Log.d(TAG, "set address" + firebaseStreetAddress11);
            FirebaseLocations.firebaseStreetAddress1 = firebaseStreetAddress11;
        }

        public static void setFirebaseLatitude(List<Double> firebaseLatitude1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "set lat" + firebaseLatitude);
            FirebaseLocations.firebaseLatitude = firebaseLatitude1;
        }

        public static void setFirebaseLongitude(List<Double> firebaseLongitude1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "set long" + firebaseLongitude1);
            FirebaseLocations.firebaseLongitude = firebaseLongitude1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where you call `queryLocation`?

Comment: Thanks John! I was calling queryLocation in the wrong method ... it works now.

Comment: ok............:)